# Procession in Pendulum Art

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, oscillators

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/Kgs9_3UH3Pk

In this video, a pendulum is formed from a paint can full of paint with a hole in the bottom. The pendulum's swing traces out an ellipse that slowly rotates and narrows as the paint leaks out onto the canvas.  Why does the ellipse rotate like this?

Comment: Might it be [a Foucault pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foucault_pendulum)?

Comment: @KyleKanos:  The precession speed is far too fast to be due to the Earth's rotation — it appears to have a period of a few minutes.

Comment: @basics:  So then why does the precession happen?  For a small-angle pendulum the orbits should be closed and there shouldn't be any precession.  (Maybe the amplitude of the swing is too large for this approximation to work?)

Comment: @basics The trajectory of an ideal spherical pendulum is closed - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_pendulum. However, one obvious way in which this set up is not an ideal pendulum is paint loss from the can, which makes the moment of inertia of the pendulum time dependent. This may explain the precession.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert to be fair, I didn't watch the video (& still haven't). I saw the title & words and assumed it was a Foucault.

Comment: @Solomon Slow answer below looks reasonable to me. I'm upvoting it

Comment: I had no time to do the math so far. Anyway, this could be a really nice problem to solve for a course in mechanics, with several variations on the theme: checking conditions on wires to be stretched and never compressed (no stiffness to compression), weight with varying mass,...

Answer (score 3):

I don't think those are ellipses, and I don't think you are seeing precession. I think the paint can in the video traces part of a [Lissajous figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve) which is what you get if you plot $f(t)$ vs. $g(t)$ on a cartesian coordinate grid, where $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are both simple harmonic functions of $t$ and each has a different period.

Here's a vid that shows a pendulum making some more complete Lissajous figures and, which shows how to construct the pendulum and why it works.

https://youtu.be/uPbzhxYTioM

The thumbnail version of why it works is, the pendulum is suspended in a way such that the part of it that is free to swing in one plane is longer than the part that is free to swing in a crosswise plane. The two different lengths give it two different periods in the two axes.